# Does GUI have shell behind it like terminal?

Tags: command-line, gui

In Unix, the text we type on terminal window is sent to shell as input. How about GUI and TUI? Does it have shell too that handles mouse clicks and keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, **a graphical user interface (GUI) is used by a shell**.<sup>**[1]**</sup>

Moreover, **Unity**, the default user interface in Ubuntu, **is a shell interface** for the GNOME desktop environment.<sup>**[2]**</sup>

References:

1. [Shell (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29)
2. [Unity (user interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the program, things like GParted are just graphical versions of CLIs. In GParted's case it's obviously the GUI for Parted. What really happens is eventually anything running needs to get down to a compiler so that the computer can understand what's happening. If you want to get a better grasp on the underbelly of a computer, learn some C code.

Comment: The compiler has nothing to do with this. It is needed to compile the program into an executable binary and has nothing to do with actually running it.